# How To Remove The Author(s) From Certain Posts

Tags: author, conditional-tags

There are certain posts on the website I'm developing, that don't need the author(s) by-line. (such as press releases)

Is there any method, that allows me to remove the author (and co-authors) for certain posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mike23's suggestion, I solved my problem with conditional tags.

---

Just insert the following in the author area of `single.php`, `archive.php` and any other page template that displays an author.

```
<?php if ( has_tag('press-releases') ) {
      echo '';
} else { 
      echo 'by '; the_author_posts_link();
}
?>
```

Using the above code, you can remove the author name on all posts tagged `press-releases`.

All posts without the tag `press-releases` will retain their author name.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to use WP's [body class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and in your stylesheet target the element containing the autor name to hide it for the page(s) you want.

For example :

```
.page-id-227 #my_authors{ display: none }
```

**Update** :

Another solution would be to use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in your templates, to print the author names only on wanted pages.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the body class function. (it could be very useful for theme design) --- But if possible, I'd prefer to remove the author(s) from the page, rather then just hiding them from sight. --- The reason? Because these posts could still show up in search results for author names, even when I didn't want to associate any author with these articles.

Comment: @Ademos, what about conditional tags ? (see updated answer). ps. if  you want to exclude posts from the search, you'll have to modify the search query, else they will show in results, no matter if the author name is displayed or not.

Comment: Thanks to your advice (and some Wordpress Codex examples) I was able to write the commands I needed. I created an answer for it, below.